# save all possible random strings in python

Tags: python, string, list

Here is my code:

```html
def randomword(length):
    allchar = string.ascii_lowercase
    keywords =[''.join(random.choice(allchar) for i in range(length))]
    return keywords

print(randomword(4))
```

I didn't get all possible random string with 4 characters.I only get one possible random string,such as ['uuph'].

Comment: You're returning around `23751` items. Does that sound right?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes.so how can I save all 23751 items?

Comment: What does "save" mean?

Comment: If by "save" you mean save to a file on your filesystem disk, you can `with open("yourfile", 'w') as f: f.write(keywords)`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it means print out all possible random strings with 4 chars.

Comment: "all possible" and "random" comprise a contradiction in terms: if you're generating all possible permutations, the result is *not* random.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like what you really want is all the possible permutations of length N from a superset.

Check out the `itertools.permutations()` method.

Or the combination with replacement mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks.I got it. This method is useful!